# Unable to retry on Kafka Main topic ( no RETRY or DLT exits)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Can anyone please let me know if we can retry on the main Kafka topic itself, when the exception happens after consuming message from the same main Topic. I am using spring-kaka, but looks like we can't achieve this with spring-kafka.

Comment: Your question is not clear; the default error handler will retry. Show your code and configuration and explain more clearly what problem you are seeing.

Comment: I am having only one topic. If the exception happens after consuming the event at the service level, I would like to post the message back to the Same topic. I would like to do so for the configured no of time. Hope my question is clear now .

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So74602308Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So74602308Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so74602308", topics = "so74602308")
    void listen(String in,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset,
            @Header(name = "my.retries", required = false) byte[] retries) {

        System.out.println(in + " @" + offset);
        int count = 0;
        if (retries != null) {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(retries);
            count = bb.getInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Count:" + count);
        if (count < 4) {
            throw new RuntimeException("retry this one to same queue, no delay");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Retries exhausted for record at offset " + offset);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so74602308").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so74602308", "test");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CommonErrorHandler errorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template, (rec, ex) -> new TopicPartition("so74602308", -1)) {

            @Override
            protected ProducerRecord<Object, Object> createProducerRecord(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record,
                    TopicPartition topicPartition, Headers headers, @Nullable byte[] key, @Nullable byte[] value) {

                ProducerRecord<Object, Object> out = super.createProducerRecord(record, topicPartition, headers, key,
                        value);
                org.apache.kafka.common.header.Header header = out.headers().lastHeader("my.retries");
                if (header == null) {
                    header = new RecordHeader("my.retries", new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
                    out.headers().add(header);
                }
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(header.value());
                int retries = bb.getInt();
                bb.position(0);
                bb.putInt(++retries);
                return out;
            }

        }, new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L));
    }

}
```

```
test @21
Count:0
test @22
Count:1
test @23
Count:2
test @24
Count:3
test @25
Count:4
Retries exhausted for record at offset 25
```